# como podria hacer para visualizar una imagen en un formulario luego de haberla enviado previamente en el mismo formulario?

Tags: django, imagen, django-forms

soy nuevo en django, estoy tratando de desarrollar un aplicativo, donde un formulario permita enviar una imagen, y luego de presionar 'enviar' quiero recibir la imagen que acabo de subir, he desarrollado el modelo, la parte de la vista, el formulario en html sin embargo luego de presionar enviar solo me recarga el formulario en blanco. las imágenes se guardan bien, pues he podido abrirlas luego entrando en modo administrador y presionando en el link que las referencia, y si se cargan.
Muchas gracias

Comment: Mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que lo quieres mostrar es la última imagen enviada por el usuario que ha rellenado el formulario.

supongo que tienes algo así en el código:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ModeloForm


def Mi_vista_form(request):
    miobj = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ModeloForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            miobj = form.save()
            form = ModeloForm()
    else:
        form = ModeloForm()
    return render(request, 'mi_vista_form.html', {'form': form, 'miobj': miobj})
```

en la plantilla mi_vista_form.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% if miobj %}
    <img src="{{ miobj.imagen.url }}" >
{% endif %}
<form method="POST" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, me salvaste si funcionó.